ZSH/Bash export variable from command substitution with spaces
I'm trying to set variables from the output of a command but bash and zsh are not respecting the quotes.
$ export $(echo 'foo=one bar="two -x"')
bash: export: `-x"': not a valid identifier

There is no obvious reason this shouldn't work, since both of these operations work independently.
$ echo 'foo=one bar="two -x"'
foo=one bar="two -x"
$ export foo=one bar="two -x"
$ echo $foo
one
$ echo $bar
two -x

Another alternative that also doesn't work:
$ export $(echo foo=one bar=\"two -x\")
bash: export: `-x"': not a valid identifier

And another I've seen suggested, that also doesn't work:
$ export "$(echo 'foo=one bar="two -x"')"
$ echo $foo
one bar="two -x"


Quotes are evaluated as syntax before any expansions take place so the quotes in export bar="two -x" are not going to work the way you expect if bar="two -x" is the result of an expansion.

Wondering, why to use echo command?

Under [tag:bash] you could:. <(sed 's/^/export /' < <(echo foo=one;echo bar=\"two -x\"))

Read (quietly) this answer to Set environment variables from file of key/value pairs, then try:this bash --rcfile <(echo 'foo=one bar="two -x"') --noediting -ic $'for var in foo bar;do echo "Variable \47$var\47 do contain \47${!var}\47.";done'

eval "$(echo 'export foo=one bar="two -x"')"


We have the following command:
export $(echo 'foo=one bar="two -x"')

The default IFS splits interpolated strings on "whitespace" (spaces, tabs and line feeds). As such, the above command is equivalent to the following:
export 'foo=one' 'bar="two' '-x"'

Changing the IFS so that no splitting occurs won't help because the command would then be equivalent to the following:
export 'foo=one bar="two -x"'

foo=one bar="two -x" is a (partial) shell command, so you will need to evaluate it as a shell command to get the desired effect.
eval "$(echo 'export foo=one bar="two -x"')"

That requires trusting the command emitting the shell command. If you don't, you will need to change the format of its output or write your own parser.

Standard disclaimer: you have to trust the command providing the argument to eval, because eval doesn't just execute assignments; it executes whatever arbitrary shell command it receives.
